# When is a topic within the domain of Physics and when is it Applied Maths or Engineering?

Tags: soft-question, education

I'm curious as to why some topics, e.g. fluid dynamics, are more often associated  with particular university departments.

For example, the study of water waves is usually something given by departments or faculties of Applied Mathematics or Engineering, but rarely Physics.

Why is that the case? Or am I missing something fundamental about what makes some studies the concern of physicists, and not applied maths or engineering?

Comment: It's purely historical, for no good reason. It depends semi-randomly on both the university and the country the university is in.

Comment: Engineering is applied physics.  And Mathematics is the language of Physics and subsequently Engineering.  All three are usually needed for most topics in physics.  Mathematicians tend to look at problem not as their physics results but as what mathematics they can apply to a problem and use those results somewhere else.  Engineers are tending to look at problems that exist and they are trying to solve.  Physicists are looking more towards more fundamental interactions.  All that being said there is plenty of crossover between the 3 areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically physics has to do with discovering and understanding the laws of nature, whereas engineering is with using this knowledge to develop technology. In other words: physicists invent the equations, whereas engineers use the already known equations.

In practice, this transition is not clear cut and many physicists today are busy with essentially high level engineering. Yet, with more mature fields, such as fluid dynamics or classical mechanics, it is rather obvious - there is not much left to discover, but many unsolved mathematical problems and useful technological applications.